# Accessing powerbi desktop from Single Page Application(SPA)

Tags: angular, powerbi, basic-authentication

We currently have a single page application (SPA) developed in **Angular 8**

What I would like to achieve is upon clicking one of the menus( Connect to PowerBI), I would like to open the powerbi desktop and achieve the below scenario.

[image]

**Scenario:**

> 1. Currently dialog box is prompting users to pick the ***Web API
>      endpoints*** from the drop down they want to connect.
> 2. Once they have selected their endpoint then the next prompt will ask their API key (**BASIC** Authorization). Because our old APIs have
>      designed using BASIC authorization.
>
> 3 . Pass the selected values ( Endpoint + API key) on the run time to
>   trigger and open the POWERBI desktop web API request? Is this
>   possible?

Appreciate any work around or help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare a .pbix file for the "template" report, but use [parameters](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/) for the endpoint and API key. Upload this report to Power BI Online. When your site knows the values for the endpoint and API key, use [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) to [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereportingroup) the template report, [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup) the parameter values of the clone and then [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exportreportingroup) the .pbix file, which when opened by the user, will connect to the specified endpoint.

If this is an option for you, it will be easier though to save this .pbix file as template (.pbit) and serve it directly to the user. When it is opened, it will show a dialog to enter values for the parameters, where the user will enter the endpoint and API key. But in this case they will not be know to you, because they will not be entered in your web site.

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thank you so much for this solution. Still I am stuck in few areas. Manage to use the parameters but our API only has BASIC authentication. So basically under web area of powerbi in the BASIC tab our `API key` will go in there. There is no way to pass the api key has parameter. Image here. https://imgur.com/a/CsjAfTU Any suggestion pls.

Comment: What is the M code of the query, when you load data from your web API?

Comment: let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL & "/api/projects/")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"projectId", "parentQuoteId", "projectGroupId", "projectGroupCode", "projectGroupName", "code", "name", "milestones", "materialLocationId", "updateOptions"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"

Comment: Even though I have used the BASIC Authentication as per my comments screenshot. M Code is not showing anything related to BASIC authentication. Any advice on this please

Comment: [Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents) has optional second parameter, where you can specify authorization headers, like in [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-Authenticate-to-a-REST-API-with-basic-Authentication-in/td-p/105202) post for example. Maybe this could do the trick.

Comment: Tried the above suggested methods but still M code is throwing error :(